# SMTP proxy to circumvent a blocked port 25

Tags: smtp

Like most residential ISPs, my ISP blocks port 25 to keep me from running a mail server. For reasons unimportant to this thread, I do not want to run the mail server on the VPS if I don't have to. What I want to do instead is get a VPS just to use its open port 25, forwarding it to my mail server, which is running at home, maybe on a different port. What's the easiest way to do this?

I want to be able to send and receive emails to and from my home server, using the VPS proxy for both.

Comment: Just use a SOCKS proxy?

Comment: Or SSH port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the mountain you are about to climb (re mail deliverability and reputation issues) , the solution is simple -

Set up a VPN server on the VPS and a client on your mail server, ensuring it has a default route out the VPN.